# Error converting varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to concatenate two integer values with hyphen in between. So when I try to do the same, SQL gives me the error.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '30-45' to data type int.

**NOTE:**
Also, the second value for concatenation can be null so in that case, a hyphen should not be concatenated.

```
example
from1 = 30
to1 = 45

case 
    to1 is null 
    then from1
    else CONCAT(from1, '-' + nullif(to1,''))  end 
AS age
//This works but shows 3045 instead of 30-45.
```

```
concat(from, '-', to) AS age
//This doesn't work out as it gives the error 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '30-45' to data type int.'
```

Thanks for the help in advance and looking forward to it.

Comment: There are other problems too; both `TO` and `FROM` and reserved keywords, so I would, in truth, expect several "Invalid syntax near keyword 'TO'" and "Invalid syntax near keyword 'FROM'" errors.

Comment: What value are you expecting here. Why would you expect `CONCAT(from, '-' + nullif(to,''))` to *not* return `'30-45'` and why would you not expect that to generate an error when you try to convert it to an `int`; it's not a valid `int`.

Comment: @Larnu: It was just an example. But thanks for the same I have edited the same as well.

Comment: @Larnu: I need the output to be there in the integer itself. Can't we consider the hyphen sign as a minus?

Comment: _Can't we consider_ Yes, we can as people looking at some poorly posted code. But you are writing code and you seem to think that the database engine does what you want and not what you write. So is your goal to subtract two integer (presumably) values or is it to generate a string that has a specific format? Think about what you intend to do with this string if that is your goal.

Comment: What do you need the `case` for if you have `nullif`? `CONCAT(from1, '-' + nullif(to1,''))` should be all you need

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code. It's working

```
example
@from1 = 30
@to1 = 45

IF @to1 is null
       SELECT @from1
ELSE 
       SELECT CONCAT(@from1, '-' , nullif(@to1,'')) as age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @FROM INT=30;
 DECLARE @TO INT=45;

 SELECT CAST(@FROM AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+CAST(ISNULL(@TO,'') AS VARCHAR(2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but you're converting the same into varchar but I need the same to be there in integer itself. This query is used in the select statement so it won't be possible for me to change the data type where it is consumed. 

Is there any way that we can keep it integer itself?

Comment: Please also add some explanations instead of a code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is trying to convert your phrase to int probably because it's part of CASE statement. It uses the first route to determine the output type.

In your case- you put NULL as the first route option in your CASE, so it is determined as int. try putting instead of it this: `CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10))`

Comment: The return type of a case expression is not the "first route" it is the return type with the highest [order of precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  of all those used. Since int has a greater precedence than varchar, the entire case expression will return int, which is where the conversion error arises

Comment: you are correct @GarethD , thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* that for some reason you think that strings that contain mathematical expressions are resolved as said expression, not an as literal string. Thus if you have the `varchar` value `'30-45'` you think it'll return the `int` value `-15`; this isn't true. This in fact isn't true in *any* language, let alone T-SQL.

For what you have, in your `ELSE` the `'-'` isn't a minus... It's a string... `-` is a minus. If you want to substract a number from another then it's a basic maths expression: `a - b`. You're effectively doing `CONVERT(varchar,a) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar,b)`... Just have your `ELSE` as the following:

```
from1 - NULLIF(to1,0)
```

This will return `NULL` if `from1` has the value `NULL`, or `to1` has the value `NULL` or `0`.